# Don't tell me that a suggested edit is possibly spam when it's an audit

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, review-audits

I had a [suggested edit audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3953234) that told me:

> Our system has identified this edit as possible spam; please review carefully

The system told me this **before** rejecting the edit, so I don't think that this should displayed for audits, because if this is displayed, robo-reviewers will pay more attention for audits and pass them, but don't really pay attention on other bad edits. So why does the system tell me that the edit is possibly spam?

[image: Nice screen with red handed circle]

Comment: That information is only displayed after you have either passed or failed, right? So how will the robo-reviewers know which ones to pay attention to? Also be aware that spam edits are only on of several classes of audits. More or less *" because if this is displayed, robo-reviewers will pay more attention"* is a serious [*"Mission Accomplished!"*](http://xkcd.com/810/) moment.

Comment: @dmckee: No, it is also shown **before** taking an action. I updated my question.

Comment: If it is doing that it is a bug.

Comment: @AlienArrays This isn't really a dupe, because it's refering to the fact that this message is shown *even* on audits.

Comment: As this question is about audits, I chose to close as dupe for "Strange Text After Passing Suggested Edit Audit" as Tim Post's answer touches on audit. I suspect it's by design as without this message being on both audit and normal reviews, people would be able to distinguish between the two.

Comment: I confirm, I've added a screen of the problem on the post to show the bug. This sentence shouldn't be displayed.

Comment: Not a duplicate. Reopened.